# S3cmd configuration not working properly ERROR: S3 error: None

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am trying to install s3cmd in centos with below configuration. But when i try to list down all buckets it give error s3cmd ls

**ERROR: S3 error: None**

I have checked python version is 2.6.6 and s3cmd version 1.5.1.2

http://s3tools.org/kb/item14.htm
http://s3tools.org/kb/item1.htm

```
[default]
access_key = ACCESS_KEY
access_token = 
add_encoding_exts = 
add_headers = 
bucket_location = US
ca_certs_file = 
cache_file = 
check_ssl_certificate = True
cloudfront_host = cloudfront.amazonaws.com
default_mime_type = binary/octet-stream
delay_updates = False
delete_after = False
delete_after_fetch = False
delete_removed = False
dry_run = False
enable_multipart = True
encoding = UTF-8
encrypt = False
expiry_date = 
expiry_days = 
expiry_prefix = 
follow_symlinks = False
force = False
get_continue = False
gpg_command = /usr/bin/gpg
gpg_decrypt = %(gpg_command)s -d --verbose --no-use-agent --batch --yes --passphrase-fd %(passphrase_fd)s -o %(output_file)s %(input_file)s
gpg_encrypt = %(gpg_command)s -c --verbose --no-use-agent --batch --yes --passphrase-fd %(passphrase_fd)s -o %(output_file)s %(input_file)s
gpg_passphrase = secret
guess_mime_type = True
host_base = vault.ecloud.co.uk
host_bucket = %(bucket)s.vault.ecloud.co.uk
human_readable_sizes = False
ignore_failed_copy = False
invalidate_default_index_on_cf = False
invalidate_default_index_root_on_cf = True
invalidate_on_cf = False
list_md5 = False
log_target_prefix = 
max_delete = -1
mime_type = 
multipart_chunk_size_mb = 15
preserve_attrs = True
progress_meter = True
proxy_host = 
proxy_port = 0
put_continue = False
recursive = False
recv_chunk = 4096
reduced_redundancy = False
restore_days = 1
secret_key = SECRET_KEY
send_chunk = 4096
server_side_encryption = False
signature_v2 = False
simpledb_host = sdb.amazonaws.com
skip_existing = False
socket_timeout = 300
urlencoding_mode = normal
use_https = True
use_mime_magic = True
verbosity = WARNING
website_endpoint = http://%(bucket)s.s3-website-%(location)s.vault.ecloud.co.uk/
website_error = 
website_index = index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few search i found solution, it was due to RequestTimeTooSkewed.

Through this command i was able to debug this s3cmd --configuration --debug

```
Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code></Error>
```

You can fix RequestTimeTooSkewed with these commands

apt-get install ntp

or

yum install ntp

Configure NTP to use amazon servers , like so :
vim /etc/ntp.conf

service ntpd restart

For detail you can follow this link http://www.emind.co/how-to/how-to-fix-amazon-s3-requesttimetooskewed